# React select use selected value

Tags: reactjs, select

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fkbeww?file=index.tsx)

It's a simple react app with a select menu and values

I have a setState to update the values.

I'd like to use the select menu to update the setState which will then update the values.

How do I use the value selected in the select menu

```
const handleChange = e => {
    setRate(e.target.value);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` element's `onChange` call needs to either be `onChange={handleChange}` or `onChange={e => handleChange(e)}`, preferably the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Think I've worked it out

`<select onChange={e => handleChange(e)}>`

Answer (score 1):

because you are not calling `handleChange`. You can update like this to fix:

```
<select onChange={handleChange}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the event, at line 22 at your onChange function, it should be:

<select onChange={e => handleChange(e)}>
instead of:
<select onChange={e => handleChange}>

Then you can access the value on your handleChange function by:
e.target.value